# Function that takes type unit

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm trying to create a function that has the type:

```
unit -> (int list * int list * int list)
```

But I was wondering, unit is an empty type (has no value), so how would it be possible to do something with it and return 3 int lists?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `unit` is not empty.
It has one value which is spelled `()` and is usually called "unit", like its type.
(One meaning of the word "unit" is "a single thing".)

Example:

```
- ();
val it = () : unit
- val you_knit = ();
val you_knit = () : unit

- fun foo () = ([1], [2], [3]);
val foo = fn : unit -> int list * int list * int list
- foo ();
val it = ([1],[2],[3]) : int list * int list * int list
- foo you_knit;
val it = ([1],[2],[3]) : int list * int list * int list
```

(Note that `()` is not an empty parameter list; ML doesn't have parameter lists.)

Strictly speaking, the above definition pattern-matches on the value `()`.
Without pattern matching, it could look like this:

```
- fun bar (x : unit) = ([1], [2], [3]);
val bar = fn : unit -> int list * int list * int list
- bar ();
val it = ([1],[2],[3]) : int list * int list * int list
```

Comment: Yes, the syntax `()` is a bit misleading in that this is an actual value.

Answer (score 3):

In SML type `unit` often represents an input/output action or more generally something which involves side effects. A somewhat realistic example of a function of the sort you are looking for would be one which returns 3 randomly generated lists. Another example would be one which pulls numbers from standard input something like:

```
open TextIO

fun split s = String.tokens (fn c => c = #",") s

fun toInt s = valOf (Int.fromString s)

fun toIntList line = map toInt (split line)

fun getInts prompt = 
    ( 
       print prompt;
       case inputLine(stdIn) of
           SOME line => toIntList line |
           NONE => []
     )

fun getLists() = 
     let
         val prompt = "Enter integers, separated by a comma: "
     in
         (getInts prompt, getInts prompt, getInts prompt)
     end
```

The type of `getLists` is

```
val getLists = fn : unit -> int list * int list * int list
```

a typical "run" of `getLists`:

```
- getLists();
Enter integers, separated by a comma: 1,2,3
Enter integers, separated by a comma: 4,5,6
Enter integers, separated by a comma: 7,8,9
val it = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]) : int list * int list * int list
```